# split() Error:list index out of range

Tags: python, string, split

```
line = "2013/12/10@19:48:25"
datetime = line.split('@')
print datetime[1]
```

Whenever my program runs, it gets an error. I dont know why. but whenever i check the datetime variable it contains this ['2013/12/10', '19:48:25] which is correct. But I cant access the second element with datetime[1] it gives me an error of index out of bounds but i can access datetime[0]. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong? pls help, im confused and running out of patience. Thanks!

EDIT: so here is the real code

```
def setTimeStamp(line,newline):
    line = line.replace("[" , "")
    line = line.replace("]", "")

    datetime = line.split('@')

    print datetime[0] #this works fine
    #output sample: 2013/12/14
    print datetime[1] #this is getting an error

def main():
    newline = ''
    cg = open('log.lg','r')
    for line in cg:

        line = line.strip()
        parsed_line = line.split(" ")


        print parsed_line[0] 
        # output sample: [2013/12/14@08:45:13.296+0800]
        setTimestamp(parsed_line[0], newline)]'
```

so far this is what I am doing. After I figure out whats wrong with the code Ill move on, thats why the program looks pointless as of now.

Comment: There must be some typo or some other mistake in your code, because copy/paste of this code works perfectly fine here.

Comment: cannot reproduce, add the full traceback maybe it's not at this split?

Comment: Do you have a datetime module imported?

Comment: You are potentially shadowing `datetime` module by using variable name `datetime`.

Comment: I have shown the semi full code that has something to do with the error. Changing the variable name did not affect the program sadly - @PaulRooney

Comment: I think I found out the problem, It is in the log file. not the program. I transfered the log file into a text file and it worked flawlessly. Sorry for the confusion. At least I learned today that log files are really not the same with text files. Even though they both open in notepads.

Comment: @OrdinaryProgrammer I don't think the log file is any different to a normal text file (never say never though). I think the most likely issue is that simply some of the date strings do not contain a `@`. You should use some `print`s, logging or even asserts to rules out the missing `@` in some of your data before laying blame on the log file itself.

Comment: You could also condense your function into a single line `datestr, timestr = line.strip("[]").split('@')`, which would remove the need for intermediate variable names. It would throw a ValueError unpacking exception if the `split('@')` didn't unpack to 2 values.

Comment: @PaulRooney Hi! Actually you are right. It's not really the .log file that is the bother, it's the way the log files is encoded which was in UNIX format. I had to convert it to dos/windows format first in my linux VM using the unix2dos tool before it would work on my parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who are still looking for the answer or odded out by why I was getting an error, it was because the file format of a log file is in UNIX text file format. Hence, the python parser will be confused with some hidden special characters while parsing. I solved this issue after converting the log file from unix to dos using the 'unix2dos ' command in linux. After this, my parser worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself seems correct but you can add a couple of `assert`s to be sure that everything goes as expected.

```
line = "2013/12/10@19:48:25"
assert "@" in line          # check that "@" is present there
datetime = line.split('@')
assert len(datetime) == 2   # check that there are 2 elements
print datetime[1]           # then it's safe to take the second element
```

By the way, it would be reasonable to use a different name instead of `datetime` to avoid potential problems caused by hiding the datetime module name.